# How to export secret keys from GnuPG including photo IDs?

Tags: key-management, pgp, gnupg

I'm trying to create an OpenPGP key with a photo ID using GnuPG and then export it, so it can be imported on a different computer.

Whatever tests I've done the photo ID never appears after the import on the new computer. As an example, I've started a virtual machine with no hard disk and a Linux Mint CD, then ran:

```
wget http://lorempixel.com/200/200/ -O test.jpg
gpg --gen-key # minimum options
gpg --edit-key -- -test-
# gpg> addphoto test.jpg
# gpg> save
gpg -K  # the photo is there

gpg --export-secret-key -- -test- > exported.secret.gpg
gpg --delete-secret-key -- -test-
gpg --delete-key -- -test-

gpg -K # verify nothing left:
gpg -k

gpg --import exported.secret.gpg
gpg -K
```

The photo is not there! How should this be done?

Comment: can you give some more information on your environment. and did the man pages / Documentation not cover how to do this? also, what steps (minus the key-material) have you taken to try this?

Comment: I've been Googling / reading the man and tried --export-options export-attributes but this didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The photo is on the public part of the key, so you need to export that, too:

```
gpg --export -test- > exported.public.gpg
```

Then import both keys again:

```
gpg --import exported.secret.gpg exported.public.gpg
```

And the photo is there.

Comment: Thaks, just tried and it works fine!

Answer (score 2):

### Problem Analysis

You can verify what's contained in the export by piping into `gpg --list-packets`; I additionally grepped for the packet identifiers (starting with colons):

```
gpg --export-secret-keys a4ff2279 | gpg --list-packets | grep '^:'
```

Which from what the manual page says should list an atttribute packet like the following, but doesn't:

```
:attribute packet: [jpeg image of size 12899]
```

Setting the export option also doesn't:

```
gpg --export-options export-attributes --export-secret-keys a4ff2279 | gpg --list-packets | grep '^:'
```

This might or might not be expected behavior; attributes might be of large size, although it seems unexpected that user IDs *are* exported but attributes are not.

### The Solution

I'd recommend to simply *additionally* export the public key, which contains all information on the key (but trust information):

```
gpg --export -- -test- > exported.public.gpg
```

And import this after importing the secret keys, similarly you did with the private keys (`gpg --import exported.secret.gpg exported.public.gpg`). The contents (also the missing user attribute packet and signatures it has) will be merged.